# Does "my internal body clock is broken" sound natural?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request, expressions

I have sleeping disorder, and as a joke, I expressed it as

> My internal body clock is broken.

Does this sounds natural? How would you say it in a natural way?

Comment: I'm sorry but this sort of question is off topic here. We are not a proofreading service. Please [edit] your question to discuss a specific area of concern.

Comment: I see, thanks for heads up. I couldn't figure out how to make the question more general. Please close it.

Comment: Although I agree that the question is not a good fit for the site, I will answer it (as a comment only): the natural phrasing is "My internal clock is broken". The having the word body makes the phase sound unnatural.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for *internal clock* or *(internal) biological clock*.

> My **internal clock** is broken.

I have included relevant examples below.

> [interal clock](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/internal_clock)
>   NOUN
>   1 A person's innate sense of time.
>   *‘After three hours sleep my internal clock woke me up with a bit of a headache and a very empty stomach.’*
>   *‘Suddenly the index within, my internal clock set off a siren.’*
>   *‘She now hopes to develop drugs and treatments that can be used to reset the internal clock - known as circadian rhythm - that controls people's sleep patterns.’*
>     1.1
>   another term for biological clock
>
> [biological clock](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/biological_clock)
>   NOUN
>   An innate mechanism that controls the physiological activities of an organism which change on a daily, seasonal, yearly, or other regular cycle.
>   *‘Don't drive at night if you can avoid it, as internal biological clocks   encourage most people to sleep when it is dark.’*
>   *‘This helps set the internal biological clock that regulates your sleep and waking patterns.’*
>   *‘Prolonged periods of exposure to artificial light disrupt the body's circadian rhythms - the inner biological clocks honed over thousands of years of evolution to regulate behaviors such as sleep and wakefulness.’*
>   (Oxford Dictionaries)

Be careful. These terms are somewhat broad. In OP's context, it seems clear that the terms are talking about sleeping. In a different context, it could be talking about a woman's fertility, for example.

> [biological clock](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Internal+clock)
>   2
>   a. The time period during which a person who desires to have a biological child, especially a woman approaching the decline of reproductive capability, is still able to do so.
>   b. The capacity to be fertile, especially in such a woman: *She was eager to have a child before her biological clock stopped working.*
>   (The Free Dictionary)

Comment: While it's not so much a hard-and-fast thing, I think _body clock_ is often used for sleep rhythms, while _biological clock_ is for fertility windows.